# Setup CloudWatch Alarms for EC2 instances in Autoscaling Group(CF)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, alerts

I have an AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup configuration that runs two instances of EC2. My question is - is it possible to attach CloudWatch alarms for both instances? For example I want to observe `StatusCheckFailed_Instance` metric for each EC2 in a group?

Usually you can attach alarms through the EC2 `Instance ID` but how to know each EC2 `Instance ID` in `AutoScalingGroup` to attach alerts? or here should be another way to attach alerts? I really can't find something useful and workable over internet.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1)

- Create your own script that's triggered on launch/terminate events
- the scripts will each be set to trigger a lambda that would read in the instance ID and create/delete an alarm

Option 2)

- If you're not trying to use the auto-recover option (which you shouldn't need in an ASG, since the ASG will just replace the instances), then you can make 1 aggregate alarm for the ASG
- Create the alarm based on the StatusCheckFailed_Instance metric with the ASGName=<> Dimension
- Set it to trigger if the MAX statistic value is > 1 (since that means at least 1 instance is failing, each instance will push its own datapoints to ASG versions of EC2 metrics)
- Since you only have 2 instances, you can just manually check both if it ever triggers.  But for larger ASGs using the SEARCH() math expression on the CloudWatch metrics console (or a dashboard) would be a good way to look through all the ASG instances and view their metrics to see which one is failing